# PHP variable string expression

Tags: php, string, oop, variables, functional-programming

I was wondering whether it is "best practice" or even recommended for my case to use a string that contains variable expressions, ex:

```
    $block = <<<HTML
    <div class="image">
        <img src="{$image_url}" />
    </div>
HTML;
```

The problem with using such strings is that I have to use them in a function so that they don't get called before their variables are defined. ex:

```
function image() {
    if( have_rows('image') ) {
        while ( have_rows('image') ) {          
            the_row();
            $image = get_sub_field('image'); 
            $image_url = $image['url'];
        }
        return <<<HTML
        <div class="image">
            <img src="{$image_url}" />
        </div>
HTML;
    }
}
```

Instead of being able to pass in the string from outside the function so that I can abstract the functionality (the if/while statment, get_sub_field), I have to define the string inside the function so that I don't get a "cannot find variable $image_url" error.

Is there a better way of doing this? Perhaps an object-oriented way, or is functional programming best?

Comment: It isn't hard to setup a simple template type system that would just do a string_replace/preg_match on keywords. And the question of OO vs functional is going to be opinion and preference. There is no right answer other than "whatever you feel comfortable with".

Comment: best practice is not to mix html layout and php functions, my function would return $image_url and then the layout is handled elsewhere

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Good suggestion. I've taken a long break from working with PHP and forgot some of these features. To answer my question, I feel like the strings containing variables is a bit of a bad practice, since there are other, simpler alternatives that don't feel so "hacky".